# iOS - How to rotate every subview when switching between portrait and landscape modes

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iOS app in portrait and landscape, how would one cause each subview in all views to animate when they rotate like the way the dock app icons do when switching from portrait to landscape on the iPhone 6P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explore the TV's settings and see if it has an option to report itself as a 1080x1920px display.

Otherwise I'd look into changing your ViewController's View's bounds to the screenBounds but with the width and height swapped, and setting a transform on the ViewController's View to rotate by 90 degrees

Something like:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,screenBounds.size.height, screenBounds.size.width)
```

Also you don't need

```
secondWindow.addSubview(self.view)
```

and

```
secondWindow.hidden = true
```

as setting UIWindow.rootViewController causes the UIViewController's view to be added, and UIView objects (UIWindow is a subclass) are visible by default.